# XSL using result-document outputs double-quotes and extra spaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to output a tab delimited text file from an XML file using result-document.  But, the output keeps including extra spaces and a double-quote at the end of each line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
    <entry>
        <properties>
            <something>HELLO</something>
            <Id>1234</Id>
            <Email>bob@bobco.com</Email>
        </properties>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <properties>
            <something>GOODBYE</something>
            <Id>4567</Id>
            <Email>carol@bobco.com</Email>
        </properties>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <properties>
            <something>HELLO</something>
            <Id>8910</Id>
            <Email>alice@bobco.com</Email>
        </properties>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" standalone="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="feed">
        <xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text" standalone="yes" indent="no">    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="entry/properties" />
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="properties" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Id"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Email" />"
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Id" >
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Email" >
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: (there are spaces at the start of the 2nd and 3rd lines. The tab comes out ok. With indent set to "no", why are there spaces, and how can I get rid of that trailing double-quote?

```
1234    bob@bobco.com"
    4567    carol@bobco.com"
    8910    alice@bobco.com"
```

Comment: There is only one `feed` element, so there will be only one result document. Why do you need to use `xsl:result-document` at all?

Comment: This is a much reduced example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the stray `"` character in the `match="properties"` template:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Email" />"
                                          ^
```

It's not only being propagated upon match of `properties` but also causing the following whitespace to become significant and also be output.

Comment: Ugh. So dumb of me.  Thanks!